# Units use for padding and margin

Tags: android, screen-density

I wand to handle the multiple screen handling in my app.

I see that in tutorials margin and padding are set in the `dp`.

I want to know if `dp` is the best unit for padding and margin? What other units are available for setting padding and margin?

Comment: It all depends on how your UI should look like on different screen sizes.

Comment: The different units available are px and dp/dip for the padding and margin...yes dp is better than px in terms of handling different screen size ...for indepth information refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android

Comment: I make the relative layout and i use the dp for margin and padding , if i run the app on different screen size, is the padding and margin automatically adjust when i am using dp?

Comment: @SohaibRaza yes it will be adjusted based on screen size and density you can refer dochttp://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, using **dp** is the best choice for margin and padding.

[The units available are](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension):

> **dp** Density-independent Pixels - an abstract unit that is based on the
> physical density of the screen. These units are relative to a 160 dpi
> screen, so one dp is one pixel on a 160 dpi screen. The ratio of
> dp-to-pixel will change with the screen density, but not necessarily
> in direct proportion. Note: The compiler accepts both "dip" and "dp",
> though "dp" is more consistent with "sp".
>
> **sp** Scale-independent Pixels - this is like the dp unit, but it is also
> scaled by the user's font size preference. It is recommend you use
> this unit when specifying font sizes, so they will be adjusted for
> both the screen density and user's preference.
>
> **mm** Millimeters - based on the physical size of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

dp stands for density independent pixels. It works best on wider ranges of screens and different densities out there. It automatically scales based on the device its been on